# Export only a selected rule from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I have a couple of rules in my outlook.
Recently I have added a rule that delays the outgoing messages by "x" minutes.
I would like to share this rule with few of my colleagues who find this useful.
When I tried to export the rules from the `Rules and Alerts` dialog - it does not allow me to export one single (or particular set) rule. 
[image]

How can I export only a set of selected rules from my outlook?

**OR**

**Edit**: Or is there a way where one could edit the exported rules file (`.rmz`) to select what rules should be exported?

Comment: Are you and your colleagues using Exchange? Because the rules can be stored inside Exchange. This article describes how to copy a rule from one person to another. http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/managing-inbox-rules-exchange-server-2010.html

Answer (score 9):

You can do the following:

- export all your rules to a file named **ALL.rwz** (for example)
- delete all the rules but keep the one that you want to share with your colleagues
- export your rules (now only one) to another file named **Myrule.rwz** (for example)
- re-import your rules using the first file named **ALL.rwz**

Comment: This alters your rules. You don't actually need to re-import anything, just cancel after exporting required rule(s).

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can see is to delete all other rules, export the remaining one rule using "Export Rules..." and then click the "Cancel" button on "Rules and Alerts" window to retain deleted rules intact.

Comment: Wow! This does not look like the most efficient way of doing it. Are there any editors available to edit the `.rmz` file which holds the exported rules?

Comment: Ask for an editor on softwarerecs: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: the file is rwz (rules wizards rules) and not rmz.